# How to check visibility of list item in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

`FlatList` of `React Native`has a property `viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs` where you can set:

```
viewabilityConfig: {
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50,
    waitForInteraction: true,
  }
```

to detect visible items of the list with threshold of 50% and after interaction or scroll.

Does Jetpack Compose also have something similar to this?

There is `LazyListState` with some layout info. But I wonder if there is anything built-in component/property for this use case.

**Edit**

I have a list of cardviews and I want to detect which card items (at least 50% of card is visible) are visible on display. But it needs to be detected only when the card is clicked or list is scrolled by user.

Comment: You have layout info, and it's enough for any viisiblity information. You need a callback when the middle item is shown?

Comment: How do you do different percentage thresholds? In addition, layout info can't give us interaction info

Comment: What is the interaction information? Do you need to know if the view scrolled programmatically or by user touch?

Comment: yes, by user. For example, when it is scrolled or clicked

Comment: clicked on what? some button that will scroll your view? I'm not familiar with react native, so I don't know what's `waitForInteraction` responsible for. Please add detailed explanation to your question so everyone without react native knowledge can understand your it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get an updating list of currently visible items with a certain threshold `LazyListState` can be used.

`LazyListState` exposes the list of currently visible items `List<LazyListItemInfo>`. It's easy to calculate `visibility percent` using
`offset` and `size` properties, and thus apply a filter to the visible list for `visibility >= threshold`.

`LazyListItemInfo` has `index` property, which can be used for mapping `LazyListItemInfo` to the actual data item in the list passed to `LazyColumn`.

```
fun LazyListState.visibleItems(itemVisiblePercentThreshold: Float) =
    layoutInfo
        .visibleItemsInfo
        .filter {
            visibilityPercent(it) >= itemVisiblePercentThreshold
        }

fun LazyListState.visibilityPercent(info: LazyListItemInfo): Float {
    val cutTop = max(0, layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset - info.offset)
    val cutBottom = max(0, info.offset + info.size - layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset)

    return max(0f, 100f - (cutTop + cutBottom) * 100f / info.size)
}
```

---

**Usage**

```
val list = state.visibleItems(50f) // list of LazyListItemInfo
```

This list has to be mapped first to corresponding items in `LazyColumn`.

```
val visibleItems = state.visibleItems(50f)
            .map { listItems[it.index] }
```

---

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val listItems = remember { generateFakeListItems().toMutableStateList() }

    val state = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), state = state) {
        items(listItems.size) {
            Item(listItems[it])
        }
    }

    val visibleItems by remember(state) {
      derivedStateOf {
        state.visibleItems(50f)
          .map { listItems[it.index] }
      }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(visibleItems) {
      Log.d(TAG, "App: $visibleItems")
    }
}

fun generateFakeListItems() = (0..100).map { "Item $it" }
```

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted. I also ended up using the list state and implemented myself

Comment: Do let me know if there is anything missing in this answer from getting accepted. Thanks!

Comment: small Kotlin tip: you can use `maxOf()` instead of `max()` for all usages inside `visibilityPercent` :-)

Comment: `layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo` forces recomposition, which goes into infinite recomposition: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216499432

Comment: The idea is good, but when you have more than one item in the LazyColumn becomes hard, also there should be a check to avoid calling this every second

Comment: `layoutInfo` is an observable property which is updated after every layout. Then by recomposition you trigger one more relayout and so on. In this case you have to use  `derivedStateOf`

Comment: Tested, and as mentioned this solution will end up on infinite recomposition.

Comment: This does not take an open keyboard into account, right? How would you go about that?

Answer (score 2):

The [**`LazyListState#layoutInfo`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState#layoutInfo()) contains information about the **visible items**.
Since you want to apply a threshold you need to check the first and last item [positions](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListItemInfo#offset()) and [size](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListItemInfo#size()) according to [viewport size](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListLayoutInfo#viewportEndOffset()). All other items are for sure visible.

It is important to note that since you are reading the `state` you should use [**`derivedStateOf`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#derivedstateof) to avoid redundant recompositions.

Something like:

```
@Composable
private fun LazyListState.visibleItemsWithThreshold(percentThreshold: Float): List<Int> {

    return remember(this) {
        derivedStateOf {
            val visibleItemsInfo = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            if (layoutInfo.totalItemsCount == 0) {
                emptyList()
            } else {
                val fullyVisibleItemsInfo = visibleItemsInfo.toMutableList()
                val lastItem = fullyVisibleItemsInfo.last()

                val viewportHeight = layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset + layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset

                if (lastItem.offset + (lastItem.size*percentThreshold) > viewportHeight) {
                    fullyVisibleItemsInfo.removeLast()
                }

                val firstItemIfLeft = fullyVisibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull()
                if (firstItemIfLeft != null &&
                    firstItemIfLeft.offset + (lastItem.size*percentThreshold) < layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset) {
                    fullyVisibleItemsInfo.removeFirst()
                }

                fullyVisibleItemsInfo.map { it.index }
            }
        }
    }.value
}
```

and then just use:

```
    val state = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn( state = state ){
       //items
    }
    val visibleItems = state.visibleItemsWithThreshold(percentThreshold = 0.5f)
```

In this way you have the list of all the visible items with a threshold of 50%. You can observe the list using something:

```
    LaunchedEffect(visibleItems){
        Log.d(TAG, "App: $visibleItems")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Visibility Tracker](https://github.com/hevinxx/visibility-tracker) works like the viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs.

```
VisibilityTracker(
    threshold = 0.5f,
    onVisibilityChanged = { isVisible ->
        if (isVisible) yourLogic()
    },
    treatOnStopAsInvisible = true
) {
    // Your composable content here
}
```